# "The Black Hole" movie version 1979: What happened after the white hole exit?

Tags: the-black-hole

While the movie version ends with the exit from the white hole, in the Wikipedia section it is mentioned that in the Whitman comics the story continues in a parellel universe. It is also mentioned that in other scripts the outcomes are quite different.
What is really interesting: The German Wikipedia claims that in contrast to the US version *Beyond the Black Hole" Egmont/Ehapa published the whole story including the last versions 5+6.

Has someone the comics and could give a more detailed overview what versions of the end existed?

**On a personal note**:
What I find astounding is that I viewed the movie still before adolescence, because you know, "Disney" are children films. I do not know if someone else feels this way, but the most important impact is that Maximillian remains for me the top one robot villain with no contenders. Hulking, silent, red, cyclopic eye and the damn swirling blades...I am still creeped out by this thing.

Comment: I've always felt the movie was pretty explicit that the good guys went to heaven, and the bad guys went to hell. It's just such a bizarre way to end an SF film that everyone wants to retcon it.

Comment: Very rare indeed; http://www.recalledcomics.com/TheBlackHole4.php

Comment: 6 250 dollar for a comic ?!!

Comment: @Kenster After the hell/heaven sequence the probe ship exit out of something which looks like a [white hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_hole). So no, it is an open ending.

Comment: Yes, they experience traveling through a heaven-like corridor with a glowing being who is probably meant to be an angel, but then the ship is shown emerging out of a bright white something back into what looks like normal space, see the very last part of [this youtube clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFv9ZRAqG1s), starting around 2:40.

Comment: In the novelization of the movie, after passing through the black hole they "become" a new universe.

Comment: What happened after the end of the movie? *People walked out of the theater.*

Comment: I read the Black Hole comics as a kid - as I recall after emerging from the white hole, the survivors of the Palomino crew encounter a parallel universe version of the Cygnus.

Answer (score 2):

The original Disney movie left a pretty clear ending where the black hole led to final judgement. Pizer foreshadowed this when they first discovered the black hole by suggesting the phenomenon was "right out of Dante's Inferno," and later quipping that

> "Every time I see one of those things, I expect to spot some guy in
>   red with horns and a pitchfork."

Bear in mind this film was never intended to be [hard science fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_science_fiction) à la [2001: A Space Odyssey](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062622/?ref_=nv_sr_1?ref_=nv_sr_1). This was [science fantasy](http://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/science_fantasy) akin to [Flash Gordon](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080745/) and [Star Wars](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) with predominantly allegorical themes and clear Christian supernatural elements. It was Disney's first venture into PG-rated films merging adult themes with child-friendly imagery. If they made the imagery more accurate - such as accurately showing what happens when a human body is exposed to the vacuum of space - they would lose the younger audience. The story had a fairly simple moral: evil gets punished, good is protected (by angels), so don't be evil. In this case, the mysterious black hole served to judge good and evil. The writers seemed to have no intent at all on letting scientific accuracy stand in the way of the greater message.

Saying all that, what happened at the end of the movie was twofold:

1. Everyone on both the Cygnus and Palomino who were afraid of the great unknown (metaphorically portrayed as a black hole) learned that their greatest fears are only dangerous to bad people.
2. There is a life beyond death, so be careful how you spend your time here.

Authorized novelizations by [Whitman Publishing](https://www.whitman.com/store/Info/History) had a different audience and purpose, so they took a more scientific approach to the story. Fortunately, the Palomino crew did exit the black hole at the end of the movie so the comic had room to grow. As you pointed out, the probe exited the white hole into a parallel dimension and the crew met alternate versions of themselves, including Dr. McCrea who was alive in this universe. They go on to new adventures as space explorers and meet an alien race called the Virlights.

As of 2018 Emily Carmichael has been [picked by Disney to reboot](https://www.comingsoon.net/movies/features/932321-exclusive-emily-carmichael-on-pacific-rim-jurassic-world-3-black-hole-more) this movie. Typically her stories do not lend well to Christian morals so likely the new movie will be less allegorical and have a more contemporary message appealing to a modern interpretation of family values. It would be consistent that her portrayal will follow the novelization into a parallel universe rather than hold to the theme of angels and devils in the original motion picture.

Comment: Without citing any sources for the "clear Christian elements" that seems a highly subjective and speculative assertion.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths - This is a joke, right? Do Hindu have white robed angels with wings flying through cathedral arches?

Comment: That's your subjective assessment, good answers tend to include evidence from other sources to justify assertions like that, e.g. third party articles where this is discussed or analysed, interviews with the creators where they talk about what influenced the design choices etc. Otherwise the answer merely reflects your interpretation and not any objective facts.

Comment: I really think linking to a reference that shows angels are a Christian element is not research - it's page-stuffing for no good reason.